# How to skip corrupt data in a file when reading using fscanf()

Tags: c++, c, file, scanf

I am having a file of about 1000 lines (or records), each line comprising of

- `int`
- `long long int`
- `char array`
- `char array`
- `int`

separated by spaces.

For Example, this is a part of file:

```
5 23432 this is 12

6 32342 a string 23

7 32211 another one 43
```

I'm using the following version of `fscanf()` to read input from file:

```
fscanf( p_file, "%d %lld %s %s %d\n", &a, &b, c, d, &e);
```

p_file is a file pointer here.

Suppose, if a line has more fields instead of 5, this function stops reading. How do I skip the corrupt record (unmatching record) and continue reading from next record?
Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT:**
I want to discard the record, and skip to the next one, rather than making any changes to the corrupt record

**EDIT 2:**

If my file has the following lines:

```
5 23432 this is 12

6 32342 a string 23 5432

7 32211 another one 43
```

The output must be:

```
5 23432 this is 12

7 32211 another one 43
```

Because the second line doesn't have required amount of fields

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  The answer can be substantively different

Comment: Voting to close - too broad.  Error recovery and resynchronization is too broad of a topic to be discussed in a single post.  Even compilers have difficulties correcting and resynchronizing.

Comment: Since your records are terminated by a line ending, and you are using C++, I recommend using `std::getline` to read the text into `std::string`, then using `std::istringstream` to extract (or parse) the string.

Comment: If you're working in C, then the most reliable technique is usually to read the line using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and then use `sscanf()` to process the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by checking whether the very character after the last number is '\n':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    FILE *p_file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(!p_file)
    {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(1);
    }
    int a, e;
    long long b;
    char c[80], d[80], end;
    while(fscanf(p_file, " %d %lld %s %s %d%c", &a, &b, c, d, &e, &end) == 6)
    {
        if(end != '\n')
        {
            fscanf(p_file, "%*[^\n]");
            continue;
        }
        printf(" %d %lld %s %s %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not want to consider any corrupt record. I just want to discard it and continue reading next records.

Comment: @SvsrkPraveen That's exactly what this statement can do: `%*[^\n]` means matching and discarding

Comment: Now my reading doesn't stop abruptly, but, this code doesn't discard the line, rather it accepts just 5 fields, and discards the other fields. But I want to ditch the whole line.

Comment: @SvsrkPraveen Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you tell me an example input and its corresponding output?

Comment: I have edited my question, please look at it (EDIT 2)

Comment: @SvsrkPraveen That's my bad. I didn't read your question carefully. Answer is updated now.